# Facing issue in updating large number of records in entity

Tags: c#, database, linq, entity

I need to update large number of records in table in sql server. For that I have used for each loop and added the values in entity and used single save changes to update the records in table. But the records are not updated in the created order. It was inserting in random order.

For Example I have created 16 key result values like k1,k2,k3 etc..in a dialog and tried to insert in the table. But the inserted order is k9,k1,k2,k5 and so on..

Can anyone suggest me to resolve this issue?

I have attached the Screenshot of my code please refer it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS3DD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3AT1.png)

```
             Objective objectives = new Objective()
             {
                        ObjectiveTitle = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(objects.Summary),
                        ObjectiveDescription = description,
                        Assignee = objects.AssigneeId,
                        StatusId = objects.ObjectiveStatusId,
                        CycleId = objects.QuarterId,
                        ParentObjectiveId = parentId,
                        ProductLineId = objects.ProductLineId,
                        IsActive = true,
                        ProductId = objects.ProductId,
                        CreatedBy = userId,
                        ModifiedDate = currentdate,
                        CreatedDate = currentdate,
                        ClosedDate = null
                    };

                    context.Objective.Add(objectives);

                    ObjectiveHistory objectiveHistory = new ObjectiveHistory()
                    {
                        HistoryDetails = "New Objective '<i><b>" + System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(objects.Summary) + "</b></i>' has been created.",
                        ObjectiveId = objectives.ObjectiveId,
                        ParentObjectiveId = parentId,
                        UpdatedBy = userId,
                        IsActive = true,
                        UpdatedDate = currentdate
                    };

                    context.ObjectiveHistory.Add(objectiveHistory);

                    foreach (var res in objects.KeyObjects)
                    {
                        KeyResult keyResults = new KeyResult()
                        {
                            KeyResultTitle = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(res.KeyResultSummary),
                            ObjectiveId = objectives.ObjectiveId,
                            Assignee = res.KeyResultAssigneeId,
                            CurrentValue = res.CurrentValue,
                            TargetValue = res.TargetValue,
                            IsActive = true,
                            CreatedBy = userId,
                            ModifiedDate = currentdateForKeyResult,
                            CreatedDate = currentdateForKeyResult
                        };

                        context.KeyResult.Add(keyResults);
                    }

                    var list = context.KeyResult.Local.Select(l => l).ToList();

                    foreach (var res in list)
                    {
                        KeyResultHistory keyHistory = new KeyResultHistory()
                        {
                            HistoryDetails = "Key Result '<i><b>" + System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(res.KeyResultTitle) + "</b></i>' has been created.",
                            ObjectiveId = objectives.ObjectiveId,
                            KeyResultId = res.KeyResultId,
                            UpdatedBy = userId,
                            IsActive = true,
                            UpdatedDate = currentdateForKeyResult
                        };

                        context.KeyResultHistory.Add(keyHistory);
                    }

                    context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

And what about something like

```
var results = objects.KeyObjects.Select(s=> new OKR_KeyResult{
//add values to params like param = s.param, aso...
}).ToList().OrderBy(o=>o.KeyResultTitle);
context.OKR_KeyResult.AddRange(results);
```

Comment: I have used four tables to add the records in context and then only I have used save changes to update the details in database. For adding the records in context I have used Add range only but it's not working can you please suggest me some other solutions

Comment: Error is the records are not updating in the created order I have already attached the screenshot . Please refer that

Comment: Is it with my solution too?

Comment: Hi Qhori, I have tried your solution too but it was not working I have attached the code snippet please refer it